# Profile picture not always loading from gravatar

Tags: bug, profile-picture, gravatar

I've setup my profile picture to be loaded from Gravatar. But in some places it is showing my identicon, while in other places, it is actually showing the correct Gravatar image.

From what I've found, this is where I'm getting the wrong image (this is occurring on all of the SE sites I've checked):

- On desktop: I'm getting the identicon next to my name in the answers and questions. (However, I get the correct image when I hover over the image to view the expanded user card)
- On mobile: I'm getting the identicon in the SE's site switcher in the top bar.

From where I've looked, everywhere else I'm getting the correct image (ex: [my profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/172297/dan?tab=profile)).